# Word Add-in Local Sideloading Problems on Windows10

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to sideload a microsoft word add-in I am working on, `ABUformat`. I have once sideloaded it successfully. I followed all the steps necessary but recently, the Add-in wouldn't just load successfully. It keeps returning a message: "sorry we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or Internet connectivity. Click "Retry" once you are back online". Since I am loading from my localhost I don't understand why the request for network connectivity. In fact connecting the computer to the internet doesn't still solve the problem.

Someone help me with this please have been on it for hours. I am developing using Visual Studio Code.

I include the screenshot of it here:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I now understand why the Add-in is not sideloading successfully. It has to do with the localhost server not started/running at the time the Add-in is being loaded. Solution to a problem like this is checking the localhost server to ensure it is running and then starting it if it is found not to be running.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you local dev server is not started. Have you used yo with the generator-office to create the add-in ? I'm currently developing an Add-in for Outlook where I cannot use the `npm run start` script, since outllok is not supported. I have to manually launch the dev-server (running on your localhost) by starting the `npm run dev-server` webpack-dev-server script.
When you ran `npm run sart` does it give you any errors in the console ?

Comment: Yes I eventually got to understand that the problem was from the local server not started as explained in my own answer below.  it is now working normally. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out